# Error encountered installing apk to device : INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS

Tags: android, android-logcat, console.log, android-install-apk

I have a `nexus 4` device with `android 5.1.1`. When I am trying to install an android application

I am receiving the following error:

```
 [2015-06-25 11:41:50 - XXXX] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
 [2015-06-25 11:41:50 - XXXX] Please check logcat output for more details.
 [2015-06-25 11:41:50 - XXXX] Launch canceled!
```

I checked the Logcat log and it not displaying anything.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to install an app that has libraries that isn't compatible with your cpu architecture. like using an emulator to run google maps through google play service while your emulator doesn't have an ARM (armeabi-v7a) CPU.

Comment: how can I install a library that is incompatible with nexus 4 cpu arhitecture?

Comment: what type of native libraries are you using? and focus on native because it is a native one that causes the problem.
why don't you use an emulator to figure out what type settings your app actually needs,

Comment: I am using the genymotion emulator and I am encountered the same error. I am using the mpchart library and an old version of xyzmo significant library.

Comment: I am using the genymotion emulator and I am encountered the same error. I am using the mpchart library and an old version of xyzmo significant library. However the application can be installed to a sony experia j device with android 4.1.2. I also installed [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) patch for genymotion but I am still encounter the same error.

Comment: one of android libraries that i used exported only 64 bits files and my phone has 32 bits architecture.